# Convert the base 64 encode and pass in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I have two form fields. I want to convert the base 64 encode from image. I want to pass it in JSON format to the next URL.

Sometimes I am getting

```
uncaught error property_img
```

How can I do this?

```js
var files = document.getElementById('floorplan_img').files;
if (files.length > 0) {
  var file = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
    var base64 = reader.result;
    var str = base64;
    var arr = str.split(",");
    var floor_img = arr[1];
    console.log(floor_img);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  };

}

var files1 = document.getElementById('upload_properties').files;
if (files1.length > 0) {
  var file1 = files1[0];
  var reader1 = new FileReader();
  reader1.readAsDataURL(file1);
  reader1.onload = function() {

    var base64_img = reader1.result;
    var str_64 = base64_img;
    var arr_str = str_64.split(",");
    var property_img = arr_str[1];
    console.log(property_img);
  };
  reader1.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  };
}

alert(property_img);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="floorplan_img">
<input type="file" id="upload_properties">
```

Comment: Why do you want to read it as base64?!

Comment: Why posting duplicates ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255756/how-to-to-base-64-encode-in-two-images-in-same-file#comment69717487_41255756