# How to to base 64 encode in two images in same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

Here i have two form fields , in this i want to convert the base 64 encode from image,and after that i want to pass in JSON Format to next URL, i tried like this but i am not getting ,some time i am getting one filed value (encoded value) uncaught error property_img , i don't know how to do anyone help me pls

```js
var files = document.getElementById('floorplan_img').files;
if (files.length > 0) {
  var file = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
    var base64 = reader.result;
    var str = base64;
    var arr = str.split(",");
    var floor_img = arr[1];
    console.log(floor_img);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  };

}


var files1 = document.getElementById('upload_properties').files;
if (files1.length > 0) {
  var file1 = files1[0];
  var reader1 = new FileReader();
  reader1.readAsDataURL(file1);
  reader1.onload = function() {

    var base64_img = reader1.result;
    var str_64 = base64_img;
    var arr_str = str_64.split(",");
    var property_img = arr_str[1];
    console.log(property_img);
  };
  reader1.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  };


}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="floorplan_img">

<input type="file" id="upload_properties">
```

Comment: Concatenating two `data URI`s do not create a new file. You can use `canvas` to create a new image containing both images, then call `canvas.toDataURL()` of `canvas.toBlob()` and utilize `FileReader.prototype.readAsDataURL()`. See [How can i create Canvas Image from image sources in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292364/how-can-i-create-canvas-image-from-image-sources-in-an-array)

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var src= event.target.result;
    console.log(src);
};
```